# How to reload table data by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How to reload table data by ajax.
when the view first is loaded, I get table data by ajax.
when I change some condition for re-sorting data, It doesn't work to reload data.
the first data still exists, and the next data is added.

**View**

```
<table class="oa-content-table">
    <tr>
        <td>                
            <div class="total">Index</div>
            <div class="title">Name</div>
        </td>            
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

getData()

function getData(){

     $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("JsonGetBillFactoryCost", "Bill")',
        data: {
            QueryType: $('#divQueryType_BFC').data('kendoDropDownList').value(),
            SDay: $('#divSDay_BFC').val(),
            EDay: $('#divEDay_BFC').val()
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {

            $(data).each(function () {

                var element = document.createElement('tr');
                $(element).data('dataItem', this);

                var html = '<td>' +
                           '<div class="content">' + this.Index+ '</div>' +
                           '<div class="total">' + this.Name + '</div>' +
                           '</td>';

                $(element).html(html);
                $('.oa-content-table tr').append(html);

            });
        }

    });
}
```

after I change QueryType, SDay, EDay condition for re-sorting data, I call function getData(). I want to reload ONLY 'the next data', I don't need the first data anymore.

Comment: I see you are using `Kendo` , Why are you not using the Kendo grid??

Comment: I usually use the Kendogrid, when the table shape is for row. But this example table shape is for column. I mean, I want to add model data in column shape. is it might possible by using Kendogrid?...

Comment: hmmm It will get complex if you use the MVC version syntax to build the grid because it requires you specify the structure during compile time. But using jquery version of Kendo grid might be useful for you.

Comment: Uhmm... If not so much trouble, can I get the example of the grid in column shape?

Comment: In jquery version we specify the column data as well. So you can always count the columns from the ajax returned data and then build the structure..

Comment: Thanks alot, all day long! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not removing the previous `tr's` So everytime you are just appending it to the existing table. You need to clear the table contents prior to appending new response. Also since you are maintaining the first tr to act as table headers in your table (not sure why you want this way. You can use `thead` for this purpose) We need to retain it ie: first tr. So place this code in your ajax success function before the `$(data).each` loop

```
$(".oa-content-table tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

Also inside your success function you are just appending the created `td's` into the existing `tr` But should actually build new `tr's` and append it to table. let me point it out. So the final code inside your success should be as below..

```
success: function (data) {

       $(".oa-content-table tr:gt(0)").remove(); //remove all the tr's except first ,As you are using it as table headers.            

        $(data).each(function () {

         return function(){ //to overcome the loop issue.
               var element = document.createElement('tr');
               $(element).data('dataItem', this);

               var html = '<td>' +
                          '<div class="content">' + this.Index+ '</div>' +
                          '<div class="total">' + this.Name + '</div>' +
                          '</td>';

               $(element).html(html); 
               $('.oa-content-table tr').append($(element)); //append your new tr
          }                
        });
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

**Update 1:** As per your comments the data was repeating for multiple records, This is the `Infamous loop issue` in jquery. The last loop value will be assigned to all the other loop data, as the data is pass by reference. To get clear picture of what this loop issue is I recommend you to take a look at this **[The Infamous Loop Problem](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)** navigate to the section where he explains about the loop issue.

Comment: Thank u so much, Have a nice day! : )

Comment: I thought it solves my pro, but It can't solve mine. When the model data is two or more, the last model data shows up twice.

Comment: @heejeongim I fixed the issue. Use my updated answer, Also take some time to gain knowledge on the loop issues faced in jquery. I have given a useful link.

Comment: Thank u! I read the post and got useful information. if that information is true, I have to correct this code. So I want to use the Kendogrid u recommanded. Like I said, can I get the example of the grid in column shape?( jquery version )

Comment: I dont have a ready example with me :(. Also it might take time to build one.. What I can say is. First get the kendo grid from jquery version ready.. then I am 100% sure that you will find a way to make the columns data dynamic.

Comment: @heejeongim happy coding !! let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: I love the word "happy coding!!", I just posted a question again. If u see this comment, can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might work!

```
function getData(){
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("JsonGetBillFactoryCost", "Bill")',
    data: {
        QueryType: $('#divQueryType_BFC').data('kendoDropDownList').value(),
        SDay: $('#divSDay_BFC').val(),
        EDay: $('#divEDay_BFC').val()
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {

        $(data).each(function () {

            var element = document.createElement('tr');
            $(element).data('dataItem', this);

            var html = '<td>' +
                       '<div class="content">' + this.Index+ '</div>' +
                       '<div class="total">' + this.Name + '</div>' +
                       '</td>';

            $(element).html(html);
            $('.oa-content-table').empty();
            $('.oa-content-table tr').append(html);

        });
    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the loop you can do something like this:

```
$('.oa-content-table').html("");
```